# sqldeveloper won't start with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory" error

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I cannot open my sqldeveloper at the first time with the following error message, and the application just hangs on startup.

However, if I leave it there and try to open it again, then it works. If I close it and then open it again, then I will have the same error.

Does anyone know what the issue is and how to fix it? Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image: java error when trying to open sqldeveloper]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not seen this before, but

Find your product.conf file

In Windows, it's under your OS User, AppData, Roaming, sqldeveloper, 17.4 folder.
In OS X/Linux, it's in $HOME/.sqldeveloper/17.4

Add this line

```
AddVMOption -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1G
```

Save, try opening SQLDev again.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me but I had to use 4G instead of 1. MacOS 12.3.1 and SQLDeveloper 21.4.0.346.

Comment: 4G...that sounds insane. Are you using Oracle Java, and what version of Java are you using?

Comment: In the "About" dialog I see:

java.home /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
java.vendor.url http://java.oracle.com/
java.version  1.8.0_251

I just tried with 2G and seems fine, but with 1G it gives the error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory.

Funny thing is it worked fine one week ago, not sure what changed.

Comment: you'll have a much nicer experience if you use latest Java 11 or even 17 - startup and performance.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! With Java 17 I get a warning message at startup (but SQLDev opens without problem apparently): is it safe to use or would I be better off using Java 11 instead?

Comment: 17 is missing JavaFx...there are a few features not available in 17 but are in 11. Otherwise you're just fine.